# Can't receive emails from my domain hosted mail

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

I have signed up with Google apps and want to use my existing emails under my domain but I couldn't receive them. How can I direct my mails from my domain to my Google apps email?

Answer (score 1):

Configure the [MX records](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=33352).

> - Log in to the administrative console for your domain.
> - Locate the page from which you can update the domain MX records.
>     You may need to enable advanced settings.
> - Add an MX record for the email server. Refer [this link](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=174125%5C) for
>     list of MX Records for Google Apps
> - Set the priority for the record. MX records with a lower number
>     have higher priority than MX records with a higher number.
> - If your domain provider enables you to set the Time to Live (TTL)
>     value for the record, set it to 300 seconds.
> - To add MX records for additional servers, repeat steps 3 through 5
>     for those servers. Give backup servers a lower priority than the
>     primary email server.
> - Delete any existing MX records, or lower their priority. If you plan
>     to continue routing mail to your legacy email server (for dual
>     delivery or split delivery), retain the existing MX records with a
>     lower priority.
> - Save your changes. Keep in mind that changes to MX records may take
>     up to 48 hours to propagate throughout the Internet.

Comment: This. When setting up mail in Google apps, it actually talks you through the whole process with text remarkably like this answer.